# QGIS 2.18 - Adding JGW file

Tags: qgis, file-formats

I have a JGW file to add some cropmarks.  I have tried adding it as a vector  or raster file but it comes up with unsupported data each time.  Does anyone recognise this file type and how to load it?

Comment: Where did you get the file? It could be a Jpeg world file. But then you would also need the Jpeg file to go with it.

Comment: Hi, I got the jwg file from the local county archaeology heritage department for cropmarks. There is an associated jpeg for the cropmarks that is a GIS map they have produced of the cropmarks but I wanted to added the cropmarks into QGIS as a layer along with all the other heritage monuments I have.

Comment: I have not come across a jwg file format before and googling did not seem to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JGW file is a JPEG world file. It tells QGIS, or another GIS program where in the world the JPEG should be placed.

For you to use the JGW file in QGIS it simply needs to have the same base name and be in the same folder as the JPEG and it will be used when you load in the JPEG file.

For example:

```
cropmarks.jpeg
cropmarks.jgw
```

Then you can add in the JPEG file into QGIS using the add raster layer functionality (or simply drag and drop it in) and QGIS will use the JGW automatically to show the JPEG in the correct location.

Comment: excellent.  Great explanation.  I now understand.